# Помогите, перегрузить оператор взятия индекса, не знаю как сделать

Tags: c++

Есть матрица NxN, нужно перегрузить оператор взятия индекса

Comment: int &operator[] (int i) это как я понимаю для одномерных массивов

Comment: Что такое "eсть матрица NxN". В каком виде она "есть"? Что такое "оператор взятия индекса"? У матрицы два индекса.

Comment: оператор взятия индекса по другому оператор индексации массивов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value_t& operator[](const Index& index)             { return matrix[index.x][index.y]; };
const value_t& operator[](const Index& index) const { return matrix[index.x][index.y]; };
```